# Is it possible to disable inlining of value classes in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, mockk, value-class, kotlin-inline-class

### Goal

I would like to globally disable inlining of `@JvmInline value class` classes via a compiler flag or something similar.  I would want to do this when running unit tests but not in production.

### Motivation

I would like to use [mockk](https://mockk.io/) with value classes.

I want to write a unit test that looks like this:

```
  @JvmInline
  value class Example(private val inner: Int)

  class ExampleProvider {
    fun getExample(): Example = TODO()
  }

  @Test
  fun testMethod() {
    val mockExample = mockk<Example>()
    val mockProvider = mockk<ExampleProvider> {
      every { getExample() } returns mockExample
    }
    Assert.assertEquals(mockExample, mockProvider.getExample())
  }
```

This code fails with the following exception:

```
no answer found for: Example(#4).unbox-impl()
```

I think that if I were able to disable class inlining that this would no longer be an issue.

Comment: Why would you ever want to mock value classes in general?  You should just be creating real instances.

Comment: What version of MockK and Kotlin are you using?

Comment: @LouisWasserman my initial reason for following this line of investigation is to work around the limitation against being able to mock primitives.  You can test against real instances for both primitives and value classes, but using mocks makes your test apply to a more general case

Comment: @aSemy kotlin 1.17.20, mockk 1.13.2, both latest versions

Comment: There's no value in a test that doesn't model real behavior.  There's no more reason to mock value classes than there is to mock primitives, collections, or data classes: you should never do it and always use real implementations.

Comment: MockK's support for value classes is limited. While it's improved in MockK 1.13, it's not perfect. Can you make an issue on https://github.com/mockk/mockk?

Comment: I've submitted an issue (with an even small reproduction case) here: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/948